# Eclipse running old version of Java program

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse 4.5.2.

Suppose I write a program VERSION1.

Then, I change some things (the amount of changes seems to be of no importance) and get VERSION2.

If I now run the program using the "Run" button, it (almost?) always starts VERSION1. When I click the "Run" button again without changing anything, it runs VERSION2. I don't see any new compilation going on between the runs and I cannot imagine why or even how this is possible.

Does anybody know this behavior? Or has at least a clue what is going on?

Edit: In my example I would change the same source file that contains VERSION1 to get VERSION2. I may, for example, fix a bug and run the code again, but it runs the old version with the bug. Only when I run it a second time (without changing anything in the meantime) it runs the version without the bug.

Edit3: It only happens sporadically. Most of the time Eclipse starts VERSION2 as expected, but sometimes, an older version of the code (that is, VERSION1) is started as if VERSION2 was never compiled.

Comment: Are the version in two different files? Or is it the same source file? Have you tried rightlicking the code -> run as -> java application? Is the "build automatically" option checked in the "Project" menu?

Comment: Same source file and "build automatically" is checked.

Comment: Sounds like eclipse not compiling your source file for some reason. Standard tricks are: Project ->Clean, Rightclick the project->refresh, restart eclipse... Wild guesses only, sorry :/

Comment: Thank you. I should have waited with the question until I can reproduce the error, so I have to be sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

**First solution :**

In eclipse,click the little arrow next to *the run button*:

[image]

And then you choose your **version 2**.It will then be prioritized.

This is a little turnaround but who works well.

**2nd solution:**

Click the same little arrow then:

- Run configurations ...
- Right Click on **version 1**
- Delete

Comment: They are in the same file, sorry for the confusion. Version 2 is only a modification of version 1.

Answer (score 0):

Save your files and clean your project first. Then run it. 
Eclipse usually does some stupid stuff;